# Adding New Objects with Entity Framework Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using Entity Framework and implementing the Repository pattern.  Every example that I've been of adding new objects is something like this:

```
class MyRepository
{
   public MyContext Context { get; set; }

   public Add(MyObject myObject)
   {
      this.Context.MyObjects.Add(myObject);
   }

   public Save()
   {
      this.Context.SaveChanges();
   }  
}

// A window which lets the user add items to the repository
class MyWindow
{
   private MyRepository Repository { get; set; }

   private void DoSomething()
   {
      List<MyClass> myObjects = this.Repository.GetMyObjects();

      // When I create a new object, I have to add the new object to the myObjects list and separately to the repository
      MyClass newObject = new MyClass();
      myObjects.Add(newObject);
      this.Repository.Add(newObject);

      // Do stuff to the objects in "myObjects"

      this.Repository.Save();
   }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is add new objects to the myObjects list (without having to add them to the repository on a separate line), and then just call something like this.Repository.Save(myObjects) when I'm ready to save them.  Having to explicitly add every new object to the repository seems to break up the separation-of-concerns model.  Is there a recommended way to do this, or is my reasoning flawed?

EDIT: DDiVita - I'm not sure what you mean by "attaching the entities to the context".  This is what I'm currently doing in my Repository class:

```
public List<MyObject> GetMyObjects()
{
   return this.Context.MyObjects.ToList();
}
```

Then in my Context class:

```
class MyContext : Context
{
   public DbSet<MyObject> MyObjects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How about another method in your repository that takes in a collection?

Comment: I tried that, but the problem that I ran into is what if some of the objects in my collection were already in the database and some of the objects aren't?

Comment: In your GetMyObjects() I am assuming you are attaching those entities to your context from the database. Those entities will already have IDs which EF should know about and update rather than insert.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the GetMyObjects method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AddOrUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn176991(v=VS.113).aspx) extension (the link is for Version 6 of EF) method on the DbSet. With this you can specify an identifier that EF will recognize as a unique value to either update or add the entity.

Let's assume your entity `MyObject` looks like this and the `Id` is always unique in your database:

```
public class MyObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

public Save(List<MyObject> myObjects)
   {
        this.Context.MyObjects.AddOrUpdate(m => m.Id,myObjects.ToArray());
        this.Context.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks DDiVita.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use AddRange

```
public Save(List<MyObject> myObjects)
{
   this.Context.MyObjects.AddRange(myObjects);
   this.Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And then your code could look like this

```
private void DoSomething()
{
   List<MyObject> myObjects = this.Repository.GetMyObjects();

   MyObject newObject = new MyObject();
   myObjects.Add(newObject);

   // Do stuff to the objects in "myObjects"

   this.Repository.Save(myObjects);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and I got a duplicate key error for the row that already existed in my table prior to running the program.  I'm using POCO if that makes a difference.

Comment: What if you filter down myObjects in Save to only that which does not exist in Context.MyObjects? Then you can add the filtered list and call SaveChanges.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I may end up doing that.  My biggest concern is that if my list is really big, I'm worried about having that extra overhead.  But for smaller lists, I can definitely do that.